# why static constructor gets created implicitly in IL DSM( C#) when we initialize a static variable in a class?

Tags: constructor, static, c#-3.0

```
class Program
{
 static int a=10;
 public static void Main(string args[])
   {
     Console.WriteLine("");
   }
}
```

in IL-code by default static constructor is created because of statement "static int a=10;" 
it is not created when we declare it as "static int a;"